# Issues with references

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the voter turnout by dividing the number of votes by the population for a few Counties. The script should then determine and return the county with the highest turnout.

I am having trouble with my order of operations and am not sure where I am going wrong, I seem to have issues if class and my def highest_turnout(data) are not on the first space but that space keeps throwing an error for my line "results" saying "highest_turnout(data) is not defined" but if I indent def highest_turnout then I get NameError "highest_turnout" is not defined.... I understand why I am getting the name error because that definition is under class when it is indented -- I just dont know how to associate with the class and get the definition to run.

```
class County:# implement County class here
  def __init__(self, init_name, init_population, init_voters):
    self.name = init_name
    self.population = init_population
    self.voters = init_voters
    self.turnout = []

    
 #calculating turnout percentage   
  def add_turnout(self, turnout):
    turnout = (self.voters / self.population)
    if turnout not in self.turnout:
      self.turnout.append(turnout)
    return (turnout)

def highest_turnout(data) :
  highest_turnout = data[0]
  global turnout
  if  turnout > highest_turnout:
        turnout = County.turnout
        highest_turnout = County
  return (highest_turnout, turnout) 

# your program will be evaluated using these objects
# it is okay to change/remove these lines but your program
# will be evaluated using these as inputs
allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)
philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)
montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)
lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)
delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)
chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)
bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)
data = [allegheny, philadelphia, montgomery, lancaster, delaware, chester, bucks]  


result = highest_turnout(data) # do not change this line!
print(result) # prints the output of the function
# do not remove this line!
```

Comment: hey LeviOwl, welcome to Stackoverflow. I added an introduction to your question what the expected behaviour is. Its better to start off what you're trying to do, than to explain what isnt working. Readers would have to reconstruct this by looking through your code first, before trying to help you.

Comment: Why does `add_turnout` take an argument if you ignore it?

Comment: Each `County` doesn't need a list of turnouts; you just need one `turnout` attribute whose `value` you can compute immediately in `__init__`: `self.turnout = init_voters / init_population`. then `highest_turnout` just scans the list of `County` instances it receives, looking for the one with the highest turnout.

Comment: (Which, incidentally, you can do with the built-in `max` function and an appropriate `key` argument.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a few issues with your code and could probably be simplified  quite a bit. If you're trying to find which County has the highest turnout you can do something like this:

```
class County:
  def __init__(self, init_name, init_population, init_voters):
    self.name = init_name
    self.population = init_population
    self.voters = init_voters
    self.turnout = self.voters / self.population

def highest_turnout(county_list):
  highest_turnout = 0
  highest_county = None
  for county in county_list:
     if county.turnout > highest_turnout:
        highest_turnout = county.turnout
        highest_county = county.name
  return(highest_county, highest_turnout) 

allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)
philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)
montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)
lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)
delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)
chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)
bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)

data = [allegheny, philadelphia, montgomery, lancaster, delaware, chester, bucks]  

result = highest_turnout(data)
print(result)
```

Comment: This should pretty much do it, good job removing the add_turnout method and just using an attribute. I would have done exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you Eugene! I have really been struggling with this (just learning python). You suggestions worked! the only things i needed to do was make highest_county = county to highest_county = county_name

Comment: No worries yeah if you just want the county name than you can access the name property. I'll edit my solution to match that.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the function highest_turnout requires a loop. You're sending it a list of counties, and you should loop through them by doing something like

```
def highest_turnout(data):
  highest_turnout = 0
  for county in data:
    county_turnout = county.turnout
    if county_turnout > highest_turnout:
      highest_turnout = county_turnout
      highest_county = county
  return highest_turnout, highest_county
```

This also requires you to simplify and rename the class method "add_turnout" to just "turnout". I dont know why you're trying to add a turnout, if it is just supposed to calculate the the voter turnout by dividing the voters through the population and return a percentage.

as a sidenote, I feel like making classes for this problem is very long-winded. You can achieve the same thing much easier using dictionaries instead. you should also rename "data" to "county_list" because this helps you understand whats in the data